# Calling SSE by using nodejs file

Tags: node.js, html

I am calling a nodejs file in HTML5 SSE My code is below but its not running.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:3000/");
source.onmessage = function(event) { } 
</script>
```

Can any one help...?

My Node file which I am calling is below.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var report = [];
report = {
    "192.168.1.96": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.98": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.97": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.99": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.110": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.111": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.112": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.123": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.102": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "dr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "du": Rndm(0, 1000001), "or": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.103": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "dr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "du": Rndm(0, 1000001), "or": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.104": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "dr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "du": Rndm(0, 1000001), "or": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.105": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.106": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.107": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.118": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.119": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.120": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.121": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.122": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.114": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.115": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)},
    "192.168.1.116": {"s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101)}
};

function Rndm(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'});
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log("request params "+q.ip);
    if (q.ip!=null) {
        res.end("data: " +JSON.stringify(report[q.ip]))+"\n\n";
    } else {
        res.end("data: " +JSON.stringify(report))+"\n\n";
    }

}).listen(3000);
```

My problem is that I am not getting any thing from that code. Thanks for your help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks like, SSE request must kept alive.
2. You need to know what is SSE request & other requests, in order to keep SSE request alive.

I've update your code as follows:

Server:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

var connections = [];
var report = [];
report = {
  "192.168.1.96": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.98": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.97": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.99": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.110": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.111": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.112": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.123": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tc": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.102": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "dr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "du": Rndm(0, 1000001), "or": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.103": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "dr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "du": Rndm(0, 1000001), "or": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.104": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "dr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "du": Rndm(0, 1000001), "or": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.105": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.106": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.107": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.118": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.119": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.120": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.121": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.122": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.114": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.115": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) },
  "192.168.1.116": { "s": Rndm(0, 2), "cp": Rndm(0, 101), "tr": Rndm(0, 1000001), "mu": Rndm(0, 101) }
};

function Rndm(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  console.log(req.url);
  if (req.url === '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' });
    return fs.createReadStream('./views/index.html').pipe(res);
  }


  if (req.url === '/sse') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Connection': 'keep-alive' });
    connections.push(res);
    var q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    console.log("request params " + q.ip);
    if (q.ip != null) {
      res.write("data: " + JSON.stringify(report[q.ip])) + "\n\n";
    } else {
      res.write("data: " + JSON.stringify(report)) + "\n\n";
    }
    return;
  }

  res.end('Invalid request');


}).listen(3000);

function sendData() {
  for (let connection of connections) {
    connection.write("data: " + JSON.stringify(report) + "\n\n");
  }
  setTimeout(sendData, 1000);
}

sendData();
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var source = new EventSource("/sse");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
</script>
```

[Here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/excellent-fire), I've put your code together & added some extra code to simulate server sent events. I found this [link](https://www.terlici.com/2015/12/04/realtime-node-expressjs-with-sse.html) useful to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

For SSE you can use sse-nodejs module which is build specially for SSE.
Please find URL:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse-nodejs

You are using 
var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:3000/");
source.onmessage = function(event) { }

in place of you can use 
var ev = new EventSource('/time');
ev.addEventListener();

I wish that will work for you.